# ScrollView moved AdMob ads

Tags: android, android-layout

Well before my ads were working fine and were always at the bottom of the screen, but now I added a scrollview and the ads move up a little bit to be right under my scrollbar.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pattern_carbon_fiber_dark">

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="339px">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:text="Silent Mode" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/silent_textview"></TextView>
<ToggleButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Silent Mode" android:id="@+id/silentbutton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textOff="OFF" android:textOn="ON"></ToggleButton>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Wifi " android:id="@+id/wifi_textview"></TextView>
<ToggleButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="ToggleButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/wifibutton"></ToggleButton>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/gps" android:id="@+id/gps_textview"></TextView>
<Button android:text="@string/gpsbutton" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/gps"></Button>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/bluetooth" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/bluetooth_textview"></TextView>
<ToggleButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="ToggleButton" android:id="@+id/bluetooth" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ToggleButton>
<TextView android:text="@string/brightness" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/screenbrightness_textview"></TextView>
<SeekBar android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/SbBar" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:max="255"></SeekBar>          

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

<com.google.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="a14ddb1a61b9fb4"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="false">
</com.google.ads.AdView>

 </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Please help, thanks!

EDIT: Picture

[UI pic http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/9397/unledyv.png](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/9397/unledyv.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You will probably leave the ads outside the scollview so they are always visible (as opposed to scroll out of the screen)

2) What is the purpose of the relativelayout surrounding the adview? That is the only view inside it: just remove it and you will get the same layout, but better performance.

Based on the update, I suggest you to try this layout (you will need to fill many blanks):

```
<RelativeLayout
...
>
<AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
...
/>
<ScrollView
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_above="@id/adView"
...
>
<LinearLayout
...
>
...
...
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The basic idea is to put the AdView ad the bottom of the screen using a RelativeLayout, and then setting the ScollView to be placed above the ads (so it does not block them) and aligned to the top of the screen.

Comment: okay I removed the relative layout, but the ads are still in the same place

Comment: OK, that's the second part, which was more a comment than the answer: re-read the first part. If you don't want to move from there, then post a screenshot of what you want to improve.

Comment: Okay, I added a picture to the question!

Comment: I want the ads to be at the bottom of the UI.

Comment: @Ciehanski Apps try something like above

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, but when I am scrolling horizontally the ads seem to go on top of my seekbar, any ideas?

Comment: @Cien Good, +1 for all the work :) Try adding some padding or margins to the views. If that does not work, I would suggest you to clean the code, and post another question, with a new screenshot (you can crop it a little bit next time).

Comment: Only if I knew what padding and margins are(in android) thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Cien get used to read the android api docs. It is an excellent resource: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using a relative layout as the root layout.

```
<RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
ETC
</LinearLayout>
<com.google.ads.AdView
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</com.google.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve the user experience, we can move the ad outside the ScrollView and use a RelativeLayout to pin the ad to the bottom of the screen. This is the needed XML markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Place very long string here..."/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adUnitId="INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```